# Include all default binds in vimrc?

Tags: vim, neovim

Maybe this goes against the traditional zen of VI, but I get very overwhelmed when it comes to working with rebinding keys in Vi, in particular what can/cannot be bound. I've had a particular headache since moving to nvim with selecting/copying/pasting using visual mode, as well as no longer having access to Home/End to jump to beginning/end of a line while in insert mode.

I was thinking that a way around this, much like I do with my tmux config, is issue a command to unbind all keys in my vimrc, then rebind them all. That way, there's no confusion to what a binding is, and I can easy change and reference a change anytime. Am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: Just use `0`, `$`, `e`, `b`?

Comment: This requires leaving insert mode thus requires more than one keystroke, and my question is much more broad than this.

Comment: I know, maybe too broad. IMHO the whole point of the insert mode is to use it only to insert. Remap caps-lock to esc and it's fast.

Comment: Can you show your `.tmux.conf` so that we have a better idea of what you want?

Comment: Effectively wipe the slate clean of all keymappings, followed by binding all keys.

http://pastebin.com/CEv7i27i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really do this. Vim treats "built-in mappings" different from "user-defined mappings". You can't really "unmap" a built-in mapping.

Technically, it stores built-in mappings in a different C struct than user-defined mappings defined with `:map`. When you do `:unmap`, it just removes it from the user-defined struct (incidentally, I gave a brief − but incomplete − overview of how this works last week in [How to find out what a key is mapped to?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6886/51) at vi.SE).

The only thing you can do is something like:

```
" Remap all ascii characters; everything below 33 is a control character
for i in range(33, 127)
        " | needs some extra love
        if i == 124 | continue | endif
        execute 'nnoremap ' . nr2char(i) . ' <Nop>'
        execute 'nnoremap <C-' . nr2char(i) . '> <Nop>'
endfor

" The above won't remap stuff like `<F1>`, `<Up>`
nnoremap <Bar> <Nop>
nnoremap <F1> <Nop>
nnoremap <Up> <Nop>
" ... etc ... You can use a loop for this as well...

" Now make our own mappings 
nnoremap : :

" ...etc...
```

And the same for `vnoremap`, etc. but this won't remap `<C-w><C-w>`, `gJ`, etc. so you'll need to add even more exceptions for that (the "second key" for these mappings isn't even in a struct, but is a `switch`/`case`!)

However. **don't do this**. Because now rely on your vimrc that you and **only** you can understand. Just learn the default mappings. This will mean you can use any Vim installation out-of-the-box, and your mappings won't be somehow "better" than the default mappings.

Comment: This is the answer I needed. Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

You can put this line near the top of your `vimrc` to reset all *options* to their default value:

```
set all&
```

But you can't realistically hope to "unbind" the "default bindings" with a single command because:

- they are not "bindings", they are "commands",
- there's no such command anyway.

You could remap every default command to `<nop>` (`:help <nop>`) but that sounds like a lot of work for very little benefit.